# Flipview not changing page on swipe. as oxyplot:plotview added to flipview Item

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, oxyplot

In my windowsphone8.1 app i am using flipview. 
after adding oxyplot:plotview under flipviewitem i am unable to change page on swipe over the chart area.

what should i do to handle the swipe over chart and flipview act differently.

```
<FlipView x:Name="flip" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0.333" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <FlipViewItem>
                    <oxy:PlotView x:Name="chart" />
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <Button x:Name="btny2" Content="mov" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btny2_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Upd" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Tapped="btnupdate_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <Button x:Name="btnRemove" Content="Rem" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="btnRemove_Tapped" ></Button>
            </FlipViewItem>
        </FlipView>
```

Comment: Is oxy:PlotView covering the entire container?  You may need to reduce the size of it by setting the height and width paramters, or putting it inside another container such as a grid with height and width set to a value smaller than the flipview size.

Comment: Yes Plotview covering the entire container.somehow if i implement the another container but problem ll remain same if user swipe over the chart area.

Comment: That's why we have the left/right arrows.  You could try putting your own arrows underneath the flipview to handle cases like this as well.

Comment: Yes arrow can be used but this ll effect the user interface. In this case chart ll be less visible. because i am showing multiple access over chart. so information ll be hide behind the arrows.